# If I want to use a javascript library like AOS in React, HOW?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, shared-libraries

I want to use the JavaScript library AOS (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) inside of my React application. How do I include it in my App.js file?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'aos';

function App() {

  AOS.init();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img data-aos={"fade-left"} src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AOS needs to be initialized, so I feel like I need to do something like I did in the above code, but it is throwing an error:

Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 8:3:  'AOS' is not defined  no-undef

How would I accomplish this in react?

Comment: I'd recommend something like [_react-reveal_](https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal) instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/), You will need to call `AOS.init()` to initialise it within your component. This can be done within your `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

In addition, you should import it by referencing the `defaultExport` by doing this `import AOS from 'aos';`

If you are using class components, this is how your code should look like.

```
import AOS from 'aos';

componentDidMount() {
  // or simply just AOS.init();
  AOS.init({
    // initialise with other settings
    duration : 2000
  });
}
```

On the other hand, for functional components,

```
useEffect(() => {
  AOS.init({
    duration : 2000
  });
}, []);
```

Do remember to add an empty array as the dependency array such that the `useEffect` hook will only run once when the component is mounted,

Comment: Make sure to add `import "aos/dist/aos.css";` or the effect will not work (`aos@next`).

Answer (score 20):

With functional components and hooks (useEffect) I did like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init();
    AOS.refresh();
  }, []);

  return (
    // your components
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You might be missing the second argument in useEffect, depending on how often do you want the effect to run.

Comment: +1, yeah you will need the line `import "aos/dist/aos.css";` and make sure that you add the 2nd argument in `useEffect(func, arr)` which should probably be `[]` in this case. I just test it myself and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Do not forget to import 'aos/dist/aos.css'; I did that mistake waste heavy time .

Answer (score 1):

First import the **script** and the **stylesheet** as follows:

```
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
```

Then **initialize** aos using useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
   AOS.init(); //You can add options as per your need inside an object
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

** Call init() function in Strict Mode in your app index.html file**

```
<script>
   (function ($) {
      'use strict';
        $(function() {
         AOS.init();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer should be removed as it does not answer the question and does not apply to React.

Comment: It kind of applies to react, because you can either use or install the library locally or use npm or yarn. If installed locally then the answer above is relevant at least it is relevant to me. But yes it does not apply to the original question.