# How to add animate on scroll effect to fetched data react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, animate-on-scroll

## Context:

I want to add an AOS-effect to multiple divs filled with data from a server, which are rendered after the initial render:

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  async function fetchData() {
    //Example fetch request
    const response = await fetch(API, {method:"GET"});
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {fetchData();}, []);
  
  return (
    <>
      {
        data.map((text, index) => {
          //add aos effect to each div
          <div key={index}>
            {text}
          </div>
        });
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

## What I've tried:

I tried to import [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) and add it as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507994/9947071):

```
<div key={index} data-aos="fadeIn"></div>
```

This had no effect at all.

I also looked at [react-animate-on-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-scroll), but it is not compatible with react v. 18.1.0:

[image: incompatible with react 18.1.0]

## Question:

How can I get animate on scroll (AOS) to work on fetched data in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I had to import the aos css files as well:

```
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize AOS in the first place?

```
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
```

You might need to refresh AOS due to reacts rendering nature, which renders new html elements on each component update.

```
  AOS.refresh();
```

Comment: Yes, I initialized it as in the question i linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507994/9947071

Answer (score -1):

I would try giving a class which animates or using Intersection Observer

Comment: Can you maybe ellaborate which class to add or how to use Intersection Observer, or provide some links?